# addEventListener firing automatically within loop - or only last element works

Tags: javascript

I have a loop, and I am creating a button within each iteration. I am attaching an event listener to each newly created button, and I need to pass unique parameters through. Please see the code below (in this case, just passing the index from the loop through the event listener)

```
for (i = 0; i <= worklog.worklogs.length; i++) {
    if (worklog.total > 0) {
        var theButton = document.createElement("button");
        theButton.addEventListener("click", alertButton(i));
        theButton.innerHTML = "Add";
        mySpan.appendChild(theButton);
    }
}

function alertButton(arg) {
    return function () {
        alert(arg);
    };
}
```

Currently, the event listener fires on only the button implemented on the very last iteration. If I remove the "return function(){}" within my alertButton function, then the event listener is fired on each iteration without the user clicking on the button.

If you have any ideas I would be extremely appreciative. I am finding other people who have had this problem, yet the solutions provided don't seem to work so well for me. Hopefully I am overlooking something simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in the way you are assigning listener:

```
theButton.addEventListener("click", alertButton(i));
```

in above code, `alertButton(i)` will call function and not assign to it. If you want to pass a value to a function assignment, you should bind value.

```
theButton.addEventListener("click", alertButton.bind(this,i));
```

As pointed by @Andreas, a working example.

```js
function createButtons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var theButton = document.createElement("button");
    theButton.addEventListener("click", alertButton.bind(this, i));
    theButton.innerHTML = "Add";
    content.appendChild(theButton);
  }
}

function alertButton(arg) {
  console.log(arg)
}

createButtons();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: _If you want to pass a value to a function assignment, you should bind value_ No. `.bind(i)` will "only" set the context (`this`) to the value of `i`

Comment: And the problem is a completely different one. `allertButton` returns a new function so it is correct to call it in `.addEventListener("click", alertButton(i))`

Comment: @Andreas I believe there is no issue at all then, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb05ghzw/). Its working fine here.

Comment: The code shown from OP doesn't make to much sense right now, imho. What is `worklog`? Why the loop is for `worklog.worklogs` but the loop itself only uses `worklog.total` (which hides the out of bounce because of the `<=` in the loop header)? And the error is not reproducible with the code shown - as you've already found out with your fiddle :)

Comment: Hey all - thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately this advice still isn't working on what I am building; not sure why. I see that it is working fine in JSFiddle so that is a mind boggling. I have tried variations of each of your suggestions and continue to see the similar results.

Also, the code is out of context. To clarify, worklog.worklogs is the array of objects that I am filtering through, but I am only filtering through if the  worklog.total is greater than 0.

Comment: Can you provide a sample by creating a Fiddle?

Comment: I will try to configure on JSFiddle. I am making two AJAX requests which I think may be interfering. Thanks again everyone for you help. I will report back when I can provide an accurate representation of my experience